# java hide url response servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Servlet that extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and it's primary purpose is to generate a PDF and send it to the client as a target _BLANK req. It is working well, but the problem I have is that I need to hide the entire URL, or at least the domain part... I've been searching a lot on the web and I still haven't found an exact needing from anyone.... Here's the method that writes the PDF:

```
private void outPdf(String pdfName, HttpServletResponse response, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) 
                                                        throws IOException {
        //setting some response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", 
                            "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        //setting the content type
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        //
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","filename="+pdfName);

        // the contentlength is needed for MSIE!!!
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
}
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance....

Comment: what do you mean by "send it to the client as a target _BLANK req"? You mean the client's browser is opening a new window/tab and then requesting the pdf? And how would you do that without a domain in the host?

Comment: It's not possible to hide the domain from the browser's address bar, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: That's what I mean, nothing else... The domain will always be there, I'm just asking if I can hide it or rewrite it without compromising the application

Comment: If you were able to do that it would be a **Giant** security hole. People could hide the domain/site that their malware is coming from. You can't.

Comment: The host is part of the URL, you can not hide it. If you take it off of your URL the client will not know what server to invoke. This a URL Sintax ||||  scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

Comment: Well, thank you all.

Comment: It _is_ possible to use `window.open` to (try to) control what window chrome is present - e.g. `window.open('http://localhost/index.html', 'myhome', 'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no');` where the part `location=no` says don't display the URL/location bar. But - browsers don't have to honor any of that, and the user can (usually) override the browser too (I never let the URL be hidden) - See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've been reading the docs and testing those configuration parameters but I can still see the Url info... Here (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) It says that location param works in Opera only, so it is not a solution for me... Still I appreciate your answer and I'll have to find another solution for this.